# Bind List of List to model attribute in thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am able to bind a `List` as an attribute of an `object` in `thymleaf`, but this list again has an attribute as `List`. Which is giving me parse error:

Binding List:

```html
<form th:object="${obj}" th:action="@{/list}" action="void(0)" method="post">
    <tr>    
        <td th:field="*{id}" th:text="${obj.id}" /> 
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="l , i : ${obj.someList}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{someList[__${i.index}__].something}" />
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

List again has a list:

```java
public class Foo {
  private int id;
  private List<Some> someList;

  //setter getter

}

public class Some {
  private int sid;
  private List<SomeChild> anotherList;
}
```

I tried the following ways:

```html
<form th:object="${obj}" th:action="@{/list}" action="void(0)" method="post">
    <tr>    
        <td th:field="*{id}" th:text="${obj.id}" /> 
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="l , i : ${obj.someList}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{someList[__${i.index}__].sid}" />
        <!-- till above line it works -->
        <th:block th:each="m, j : ${obj.someList.get(__${i.index}__).anotherList}">
           <!-- till above line no error -->
           <input type="hidden" th:field="*{someList[__${i.index}__].getAnotherList().get(__${j.index}__).id}" />" />
           <!-- error on above line / no readable property -->
        </th:block>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

I have tried all possible combinations of accessing list by index/by get() and field/getters  but no luck. Please help.

Comment: In this case `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{someList[__${i.index}__].something}" />` is it not sufficient to write `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{l.something}" />` Same way you can try for other loops as well. Just use the loop variable instead of using the index. Because the syntax you are trying to use `someVariable[index]` is for maps.